# Android 64 bits compatibility and 'armeabi'?

Tags: java, android, google-play, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

Google recently informed the developer that the apps have to be 64 bits compatible.

We have to check if the bundle contains arm64-v8a and x86_64 folders.

In my app, I have got arm64-v8a folder but also 'simple' 'armeabi' and 'x86' folders (without -v7 or -v8 extensions)

Are these kinds of folders ok for the 64 bits compatibility? How to check if the associated libs are 64 bits compatible ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`armeabi` is an old ABI, compatible with the ARMv5 architecture. It is no longer supported by the NDK (i.e. you can't build for it with recent versions of the NDK).

The 64-bit ABIs are `arm64-v8a` and `x86_64`.

`armeabi-v7a` is 32-bit, but such devices *may* still be common (I haven't looked at any statistics), so it might be a good idea to still build for it.

As for 32-bit `x86` devices, I'm not sure if any Android device have ever been made that uses non-64-bit x86 processors. I guess there may be some really old PCs to which Android has been ported by enthusiasts.